# Livewire: How to pass an error message from a middleware to a page component?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, middleware, laravel-livewire

I have a middleware that restricts who's accessing a group of urls. In case it is a customer, it simply redirects elsewhere with an error message

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    if ($user = auth()->user()) {
        if ($user->type == User::TYPE_CUSTOMER) {
            return redirect()
                ->route('login')
                ->withErrors('Access restricted to employees', 'login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

*login* route is a livewire page component that will display the error message:

```php
<form class="my-auto py-5" wire:submit="login">
    ...

    @error('login')<div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>@enderror

    ...
</form>
```

It shows up correctly when I add an error inside the component. But, in case it came from my middleware redirection, it wont display anything.

Comment: You have to specify Laravel and Livewire version. Thanks.

Comment: @GhanuBha Laravel 10 - LW 3

Comment: Solution: Put this code inside the component. `public function __construct() {
        $this->setErrorBag( session('errors')->getBag('*') );
    }`

Comment: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/main/src/Features/SupportValidation/HandlesValidation.php#L54